# Kotlin: NetworkOnMainThreadException error when trying to run InetAddress.isReachable()

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi I am very new to android studio and a lot seems to have changed with Kotlin. Most of what I have found online is depcrecated.

I am simply trying to see if a device is connected to the network, just like the ping command in windows command prompt. This `hasConnection()` function should change some text on the screen. I am just trying to get it to work with anything.

```
import java.net.InetAddress

...

private fun hasConnection() {
        var address: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1")
        val timeout = 1500
        if (address.isReachable(timeout)){
            status.text = "Available"
        }else{
            status.text = "Disconnected"
        }
    }
```

I have added these two permissions in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The code was running, but showing disconnected and now it won't run at all without crashing. I am receiving the error `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` when `address.isReachable()` is executed. Am I doing this right at all or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the exception says you are trying to do a network call on main thread which is prohibited.

An easy way to fix this would be to make the function suspendable and switch to a background thread

```kotlin
private suspend fun hasConnection() {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var address: InetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.1")
        val timeout = 1500
        if (address.isReachable(timeout)){
            status.text = "Available"
        }else{
            status.text = "Disconnected"
        }
    }
}
```

When calling `hasConnection()` use `lifecycleScope` from Activity level to launch a coroutine which will call your hasConnection()

------------- Somewhere in your Activity -------------

```kotlin
lifecycleScope.launch {
    hasConnection()
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you for the help!